# I'm trying to make a teamspeak server on Linux Centos 7

Tags: linux

I'm Trying to make a teamspeak 3 server on Linux Centos 7, and I've been using this guide: http://servermuffin.blogspot.com/2015/07/installing-teamspeak-3-server-with.html

After step 23, I get this error:

```
teamspeak3.service - TeamSpeak3 Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/teamspeak3.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2015-12-24 21:09:37 EST; 753ms ago
  Process: 30252 ExecStop=/srv/teamspeak3/ts3server_startscript.sh stop (code=exited, status=7)
  Process: 30241 ExecStart=/srv/teamspeak3/ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh inifile=ts3server.ini (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 30241 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Then after looking into the logs a bit more, I find these errors:

```
2015-12-24 23:21:56.814985|ERROR   |DatabaseQuery |   | mysql_real_connect() failed with error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (107)

2015-12-24 23:21:56.815057|CRITICAL|ServerLibPriv |   | Server() unable to initialize database
```

Comment: mariadb isn't running.  Try `service mysql start`.

Comment: The database you configured in steps 11 and 13 isn't working, as chicks pointed out, maybe you want to set it back to the default SQLite.